# Why don't my OpenGL textures work?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to resurrect an old project I worked on at uni.

It's a basic OpenGL animation with some camera controls and model loading. I've got it working, but I can't figure out why textures aren't being loaded for the 'skybox' or the 'cloud planes'.

I'm sure they worked with almost identical code a few years back. The biggest change I've made is porting from SDL to GLUT, but I don't see how that would affect things.

Here are some of the lines related to rendering the skybox:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[i]);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, face);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texture);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

I don't get any warnings or runtime exceptions. The textures simply don't show.

I have things like this in my code: `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);` and `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

Any ideas? I'd really love to get this working properly again.

The full source is here:

```
//Camera start location and rotation, boundaries are -0.5 -> +0.5 in each axis.
#define CAMERA_START_X -0.6
#define CAMERA_START_Y -0.2
#define CAMERA_START_Z -1.8
#define CAMERA_START_R 330
#define CAMERA_START_MOMENTUM 0.15

//Camera keyboard-event motion speed per second, independent of frame rate or machine.
#define CAMERA_ROTATION 100
#define CAMERA_ELEVATION 2
#define CAMERA_MOMENTUM 0.1

//Cloud plane configuration constants.
#define CLOUDS 12
#define CLOUD_SECTIONS 3
#define CLOUD_INNER_PLANES 0.2
#define CLOUD_OUTER_PLANES 0.8

//Frame rate, lowering the frame rate may improve performance on older computers.
#define FPS 60

//Other global constants.
#define PI 3.141592
#define SCALE_FACTOR 0.0001

//Print OpenGL errors to console if true.
#define DEBUG false

#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include "glm.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//*****************************************
//           Global Variables
//*****************************************

//Use glm's texture id variable to maintain consistency.
extern GLenum _glmTextureTarget;

//Models.
GLMmodel* eagle;
GLMmodel* airplane;

//Cloud plane.
float cloudPlaneV[CLOUDS][CLOUDS][7][CLOUD_SECTIONS][3];
GLuint cloudTexture;

//Camera location and rotation.
float cameraX = CAMERA_START_X * SCALE_FACTOR;
float cameraY = CAMERA_START_Y * SCALE_FACTOR;
float cameraZ = CAMERA_START_Z * SCALE_FACTOR;
float cameraR = CAMERA_START_R;

//Key event values for camera control.
float rotationDirection = 0;
float elevationDirection = 0;
float momentumDirection = 0;

//Skybox texture indices.
GLuint skybox[6];

//Skybox vertices.
GLfloat vertices[8][3] =
  {{-1, -1, -1}, // 0: left,  bottom, back
   {-1, -1, +1}, // 1: left,  bottom, front
   {-1, +1, -1}, // 2: left,  top,    back
   {-1, +1, +1}, // 3: left,  top,    front
   {+1, -1, -1}, // 4: right, bottom, back
   {+1, -1, +1}, // 5: right, bottom, front
   {+1, +1, -1}, // 6: right, top,    back
   {+1, +1, +1}};// 7: right, top,    front

//Skybox cube faces.
GLubyte faces[6][4] =
  {{1, 0, 2, 3}, // 0: west
   {4, 5, 7, 6}, // 1: east
   {4, 0, 1, 5}, // 2: below
   {7, 3, 2, 6}, // 3: above
   {5, 1, 3, 7}, // 4: south
   {0, 4, 6, 2}};// 5: north

//Standard texture winding.
GLfloat texture[4][2] =
  {{0.0, 0.0}, // 0: left,  bottom
   {1.0, 0.0}, // 1: right, bottom
   {1.0, 1.0}, // 2: right, top
   {0.0, 1.0}};// 3: left,  top

//Animation variables.
bool fullscreen = 0;
float window_w, window_h;
bool forceReshape = false;
int frame = -1;
bool paused = false;
float momentum = CAMERA_START_MOMENTUM * SCALE_FACTOR;
float momentumBeforePause;

float planePriorX = 0, planePriorY = 0, planePriorZ = 0;
float planePostX = 0, planePostY = 0, planePostZ = 0;
float planeRotX = 0, planeRotY = 0, planeRotZ = 0;

float eaglePriorX = -0.5, eaglePriorY = 0.03, eaglePriorZ = 0.1;
float eaglePostX = 0, eaglePostY = 0, eaglePostZ = 0;
float eagleRotX = 0, eagleRotY = 0, eagleRotZ = 0;

//*****************************************
//           Loading Objects
//*****************************************

void loadObjects() {
  eagle = glmReadOBJ("resources/models/eagle.obj");
  glmVertexNormals(eagle, 180.0, false);
  glmUnitize(eagle);

  airplane = glmReadOBJ("resources/models/airplane.obj");
  glmVertexNormals(airplane, 180.0, false);
  glmUnitize(airplane);
}

//*****************************************
//               Camera
//*****************************************

void updateCamera() {
  //Reset position and rotation.
  glLoadIdentity();

  //Camera rotation.
  cameraR += rotationDirection * CAMERA_ROTATION / FPS;
  if (cameraR < 0) cameraR += 360;
  if (cameraR > 360) cameraR -= 360;

  //Camera location.
  momentum += momentumDirection * CAMERA_MOMENTUM * SCALE_FACTOR / FPS;
  if (momentum < 0) momentum = 0;
  cameraX += momentum * -sin(cameraR * PI / 180);
  cameraY += elevationDirection * CAMERA_ELEVATION * SCALE_FACTOR / FPS;
  cameraZ += momentum * cos(cameraR * PI / 180);

  //Move the world, not the camera.
  glRotatef(cameraR, 0, 1, 0);
  glTranslatef(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);
}

//*****************************************
//                Skybox
//*****************************************

void loadSkybox() {
  GLfloat width = 600, height = 600;
  skybox[0] = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/skybox/west.jpeg",   GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
  skybox[1] = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/skybox/east.jpeg",   GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
  skybox[2] = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/skybox/bottom.jpeg", GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
  skybox[3] = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/skybox/top.jpeg",    GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
  skybox[4] = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/skybox/south.jpeg",  GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
  skybox[5] = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/skybox/north.jpeg",  GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
}

//Draws the skybox.
void drawSkybox() {
  //Disable lighting, enable textures.
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  //Augment such that camera is at the center.
  GLfloat center[8][3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    center[i][0] = vertices[i][0] - cameraX;
    center[i][1] = vertices[i][1] - cameraY;
    center[i][2] = vertices[i][2] - cameraZ;
  }

  //Draw eace face.
  GLfloat face[4][3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        face[j][k] = center[faces[i][j]][k];
      }
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox[i]);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, face);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
  }

  //Enable lighting, disable textures.
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

//*****************************************
//             Cloud Plane
//*****************************************

void calculateCloudPlane() {
  //Calculate the increment.
  float incr = 2 * PI / CLOUD_SECTIONS;

  //Use cosArr and sinArr to reuse the sine and cosine calculation.
  float cosArr[CLOUD_SECTIONS + 1], sinArr[CLOUD_SECTIONS + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUD_SECTIONS + 1; i++) {
    cosArr[i] = cos(i * incr);
    sinArr[i] = sin(i * incr);
  }

  //Calculate a circle.
  float circle[CLOUD_SECTIONS][3];
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUD_SECTIONS; i++) {
    circle[i][0] = cosArr[i];
    circle[i][1] = 0;
    circle[i][2] = sinArr[i];
  }

  //Calculate a cloud from the circle.
  float cloud[7][CLOUD_SECTIONS][3];
  float xScale, zScale, xTrans, zTrans;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      //Scale everything down quite a bit, we only want a light covering.
      case 0: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = 0; zTrans = 0;
      break;
      case 1: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = 0.0625; zTrans = 0;
      break;
      case 2: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = -0.0625; zTrans = 0;
      break;
      case 3: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = 0.0625 * cos(60 * PI / 180); zTrans = 0.0625 * sin(60 * PI / 180);
      break;
      case 4: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = 0.0625 * cos(120 * PI / 180); zTrans = 0.0625 * sin(120 * PI / 180);
      break;
      case 5: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = 0.0625 * cos(240 * PI / 180); zTrans = 0.0625 * sin(240 * PI / 180);
      break;
      case 6: xScale = 0.0625; zScale = 0.0625; xTrans = 0.0625 * cos(300 * PI / 180); zTrans = 0.0625 * sin(300 * PI / 180);
      break;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < CLOUD_SECTIONS; j++) {
      cloud[i][j][0] = circle[j][0] * xScale + xTrans;
      cloud[i][j][1] = circle[j][1];
      cloud[i][j][2] = circle[j][2] * zScale + zTrans;
    }
  }

  //Calculate a cloud plane from the cloud.
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUDS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < CLOUDS; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < CLOUD_SECTIONS; l++) {
          cloudPlaneV[i][j][k][l][0] = cloud[k][l][0] - CLOUDS / 2 + i;
          cloudPlaneV[i][j][k][l][1] = cloud[k][l][1];
          cloudPlaneV[i][j][k][l][2] = cloud[k][l][2] - CLOUDS / 2 + j;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //Load texture.
  float width = 256, height = 256;
  cloudTexture = glmLoadTexture("resources/textures/cloud.jpeg", GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, &width, &height);
}

//Draws 4 planes containing 'cloud' type objects with parameters defined as constants above.
void drawCloudPlane() {
  glPushMatrix();
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  //Move the plane with camera, utilises integer truncation.
  int xOffset = -cameraX / SCALE_FACTOR;
  float yOffset = -cameraY / SCALE_FACTOR;
  int zOffset = -cameraZ / SCALE_FACTOR;
  glTranslatef(xOffset, yOffset, zOffset);

  //Bind data pointers.
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cloudTexture);
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, cloudPlaneV);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texture);

  //Top plane.
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0, CLOUD_OUTER_PLANES, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUDS * CLOUDS * 7; i++) {
    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, i * CLOUD_SECTIONS, CLOUD_SECTIONS);
  }
  glPopMatrix();

  //2nd plane.
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0, CLOUD_INNER_PLANES, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUDS * CLOUDS * 7; i++) {
    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, i * CLOUD_SECTIONS, CLOUD_SECTIONS);
  }
  glPopMatrix();

  //3rd plane.
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0, -CLOUD_INNER_PLANES, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUDS * CLOUDS * 7; i++) {
    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, i * CLOUD_SECTIONS, CLOUD_SECTIONS);
  }
  glPopMatrix();

  //Bottom plane.
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0, -CLOUD_OUTER_PLANES, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < CLOUDS * CLOUDS * 7; i++) {
    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, i * CLOUD_SECTIONS, CLOUD_SECTIONS);
  }
  glPopMatrix();

  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glPopMatrix();
}

//*****************************************
//                Lights
//*****************************************

//Set up lights at points on the skybox that match the textures.
void setupLights() {
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(_glmTextureTarget);
  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
  glEnable(GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);

  //Set global ambience.
  GLfloat global_ambient[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1};
  glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);

  //Set up a light source at the sun's location.
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  GLfloat light0_ambient[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
  GLfloat light0_diffuse[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1};
  GLfloat light0_specular[] = {0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1};
  GLfloat light0_position[] = {-1, 1, -1, 1};

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light0_ambient);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light0_diffuse);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light0_specular);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_position);

  //Set up a light source at the sun's reflection.
  //The reflection is half as bright as the sun.
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
  GLfloat light1_ambient[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
  GLfloat light1_diffuse[] = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1};
  GLfloat light1_specular[] = {0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 1};
  GLfloat light1_position[] = {-1, -1, -1, 1};

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, light1_ambient);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light1_diffuse);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, light1_specular);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light1_position);
}

//This augments the lighting to match the skybox, required after camera rotation.
void augmentLights() {
  GLfloat light0_position[] = {-1 / SCALE_FACTOR, 1 / SCALE_FACTOR, -1 / SCALE_FACTOR, 1};
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_position);

  GLfloat light1_position[] = {-1 / SCALE_FACTOR, -1 / SCALE_FACTOR, -1 / SCALE_FACTOR, 1};
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light1_position);
}

//*****************************************
//              Main Scene
//*****************************************

void drawEagle() {
  glPushMatrix();

  //Scale the eagle down to size.
  glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

  //Face forward.
  glRotatef(180, 0, 1, 0);

  glmDraw(eagle, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL);

  glPopMatrix();
}

void drawAirplane() {
  glPushMatrix();

  //Rotate the plane so that it faces forward.
  glRotatef(270, 1, 0, 0);
  glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);

  glmDraw(airplane, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL | GLM_TEXTURE);

  glPopMatrix();
}

//Keeps angles within bounds - prevents overflow.
void bounds(float &angle) {
  if (angle > 360) angle -= 360;
  if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
}

void drawScene() {
  glPushMatrix();

  //Set the animation control variables.
  if (!paused) frame++;
  int ticks = frame % 1440;
  if (frame % 1440 == 0) {
    ticks = 0;

    //Reset animation object positions and rotations.
    planePriorX = 0, planePriorY = 0, planePriorZ = 0;
    planePostX = 0, planePostY = 0, planePostZ = 0;
    planeRotX = 0, planeRotY = 0, planeRotZ = 0;

    eaglePriorX = -0.5, eaglePriorY = 0.03, eaglePriorZ = -0.1;
    eaglePostX = 0, eaglePostY = 0, eaglePostZ = 0;
    eagleRotX = 0, eagleRotY = 0, eagleRotZ = 0;
  }

  //Apply scene transformations.
  glRotatef(30, 0, 1, 0);
  glTranslatef(0, 0, -1500 * frame * SCALE_FACTOR);

  //Make sure angles are in bounds.
  bounds(planeRotX); bounds(planeRotY); bounds(planeRotZ);
  bounds(eagleRotX); bounds(eagleRotY); bounds(eagleRotZ);

  if (!paused) {
    //Airplane transformation events.
    //Constant swaying.
    planeRotZ -= 0.5 * cos(ticks * 2 * PI / 180);
    planePostY -= 0.01 * cos(ticks * PI / 180);

    //Spin upside-down.
    if (ticks >= 180 && ticks < 360) planeRotZ -= PI * 0.5 * sin(ticks * PI / 180);

    //Spin back round.
    if (ticks >= 360 && ticks < 540) planeRotZ += PI * 0.5 * sin(ticks * PI / 180);

    //Dive.
    if (ticks >= 720 && ticks < 900) {
      planeRotX -= 0.25 * PI * sin(ticks * 2 * PI / 180);
      planePriorY -= 0.005 * PI * sin(ticks * PI / 180);
      planePriorZ -= 0.01 * PI * sin(ticks * 0.5 * PI / 180);
    }

    //Loop-the-loop
    if (ticks >= 900 && ticks < 1220) {
      planeRotX += 1;
      planePriorY += 0.015 * PI * sin((ticks - 180) * PI / 180);
      planePriorZ -= 0.015 * PI * cos((ticks - 180) * PI / 180);
    }

    //Reset position.
    if (ticks >= 1220 && ticks < 1440) {
      // These values were found by minimising errors using binary division.
      planeRotX -= 0.1262345 * PI * sin(ticks * PI / 180);
      planePriorY -= 0.002379563 * PI * sin(ticks * 0.5 * PI / 180);
      planePriorZ -= 0.003826425 * PI * sin(ticks * 0.5 * PI / 180);
    }

    //Eagle transformation events.
    //Set default position.
    eaglePriorX = -1;
    eaglePriorZ = 0.4;

    //Set start position over left wing.
    if (ticks >= 0 && ticks < 180) {
      eaglePriorX = -0.5;
      eaglePriorY = 0.03;
      eaglePriorZ = -0.1;
    }

    //Move a little with the wing.
    if (ticks >= 0 && ticks < 90) {
      eagleRotZ -= cos(ticks * 2 * PI / 180);
      eaglePostY -= 0.009 * sin(ticks * 2 * PI / 180);
    }

    //Move back, up and left.
    if (ticks >= 90 && ticks < 180) {
      eaglePriorX -= (float)0.5 / 90 * (ticks - 90);
      eaglePriorZ += (float)0.5 / 90 * (ticks - 90);
      eaglePostY += 0.009 * sin((ticks - 90) * 2 * PI / 180);
    }

    //Swaying.
    if (ticks >= 90 && ticks < 1350) {
      eagleRotZ -= 0.6 * cos((ticks + 90) * PI / 180);
      eaglePostY -= 0.01 * cos((ticks + 90) * 2 * PI / 180);
    }

    //Avoid plane collision.
    if (ticks >= 360 && ticks < 540) eagleRotZ += 0.25 * PI * sin(ticks * 2 * PI / 180);

    //Glide from side to side.
    if (ticks >= 720 && ticks < 1080) eaglePriorX += 0.4 * PI * sin(ticks * 0.5 * PI / 180);

    //Move back to start position.
    if (ticks >= 1350 && ticks < 1440) {
      eaglePriorX += (float)0.5 / 90 * (ticks - 1350);
      eaglePriorZ -= (float)0.5 / 90 * (ticks - 1350);
    }

    //Avoid plane collision.
    if (ticks >= 1400 && ticks < 1420) eaglePriorY += 0.01;
    if (ticks >= 1420 && ticks < 1440) eaglePriorY -= 0.01;
  }

  //Apply the transformations then draw the airplane.
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(planePriorX, planePriorY, planePriorZ);
  glRotatef(planeRotX, 1, 0, 0);
  glRotatef(planeRotY, 0, 1, 0);
  glRotatef(planeRotZ, 0, 0, 1);
  glTranslatef(planePostX, planePostY, planePostZ);
  drawAirplane();
  glPopMatrix();

  //Apply the transformations then draw the eagle.
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(eaglePriorX, eaglePriorY, eaglePriorZ);
  glRotatef(eagleRotX, 1, 0, 0);
  glRotatef(eagleRotY, 0, 1, 0);
  glRotatef(eagleRotZ, 0, 0, 1);
  glTranslatef(eaglePostX, eaglePostY, eaglePostZ);
  drawEagle();
  glPopMatrix();
  glPopMatrix();
}

//*****************************************
//                 GLUT
//*****************************************

//Initialisation function.
void init(int argc, char **argv) {
  //Initialise GLUT.
  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  // Use doule buffering.
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(760, 760);

  //Create window.
  glutCreateWindow("Come Fly With Me - by Chris Patuzzo");

  //Set up camera.
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.00001, 1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

  //Set the clear color.
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

  //Use z-buffer, lighting, normal scaling.
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  //Set up two lights; the sun and its reflection.
  setupLights();

  //Use vertex arrays.
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  //Load skybox and objects.
  loadSkybox();
  loadObjects();

  //Calculate cloud plane.
  calculateCloudPlane();
}

void reshape(int width, int height) {
  int min = (width > height) ? height : width;
  glViewport((width - min) / 2, (height - min) / 2, min, min);
}

//Main display loop.
void display() {
  //Clear buffers.
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //Augment camera, draw skybox.
  updateCamera();
  drawSkybox();

  //Scale the world and reset light positions.
  glScalef(SCALE_FACTOR, SCALE_FACTOR, SCALE_FACTOR);
  augmentLights();

  //Draw the plane containing clouds and the main scene.
  drawCloudPlane();
  drawScene();

  //Swap buffers.
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int n) {
  if (DEBUG) {
    printf("%s\n", gluErrorString(glGetError()));
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  if (forceReshape) {
    float w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    float h = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    reshape(w, h);
  }

  glutPostRedisplay();
  glutTimerFunc(1000 / FPS, timer, 0);
}

void keyDown(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'q': exit(0);

    case 'w': momentumDirection++;  break;
    case 'a': rotationDirection--;  break;
    case 's': momentumDirection--;  break;
    case 'd': rotationDirection++;  break;
    case '=': elevationDirection--; break;
    case '-': elevationDirection++; break;

    case '0': momentum = 0; break;

    case ' ':
      if (paused) {
        paused = false;
        momentum = momentumBeforePause;
      }
      else {
        paused = true;
        momentumBeforePause = momentum;
        momentum = 0;
      }
    break;


    case 'r':
      //Reset the camera.
      cameraX = CAMERA_START_X * SCALE_FACTOR;
      cameraY = CAMERA_START_Y * SCALE_FACTOR;
      cameraZ = CAMERA_START_Z * SCALE_FACTOR;
      cameraR = CAMERA_START_R;

      momentum = CAMERA_START_MOMENTUM * SCALE_FACTOR;
      rotationDirection  = 0;
      elevationDirection = 0;
      momentumDirection  = 0;

      //Reset animation frame, set unpaused.
      frame = -1;
      paused = false;

      //Reset animation object positions and rotations.
      planePriorX = 0, planePriorY = 0, planePriorZ = 0;
      planePostX = 0, planePostY = 0, planePostZ = 0;
      planeRotX = 0, planeRotY = 0, planeRotZ = 0;

      eaglePriorX = -0.5, eaglePriorY = 0.03, eaglePriorZ = -0.1;
      eaglePostX = 0, eaglePostY = 0, eaglePostZ = 0;
      eagleRotX = 0, eagleRotY = 0, eagleRotZ = 0;
    break;

    case 'p':
      //Pause the animation.
      paused = true;
      momentumBeforePause = momentum;
      momentum = 0;

      //Set frame.
      frame = 605;

      //Move the camera.
      cameraX = 0.004524;
      cameraY = 0.000052;
      cameraZ = 0.007764;
      cameraR = 306;

      //Reset animation object positions and rotations.
      planePriorX = 0, planePriorY = -0.871533, planePriorZ = -1.577791;
      planePostX = 0, planePostY = -0.44244, planePostZ = 0;
      planeRotX = 312, planeRotY = 0, planeRotZ = 13.651090;

      eaglePriorX = -1, eaglePriorY = 0.03, eaglePriorZ = 0.4;
      eaglePostX = 0, eaglePostY = -0.293748, eaglePostZ = 0;
      eagleRotX = 0, eagleRotY = 0, eagleRotZ = 18.295479;
    break;

    case 'y':
      //Pause the animation.
      paused = true;
      momentumBeforePause = momentum;
      momentum = 0;

      //Set frame.
      frame = 224;

      //Move the camera.
      cameraX = 0.001829;
      cameraY = -0.000004;
      cameraZ = 0.00298;
      cameraR = 138;

      //Reset animation object positions and rotations.
      planePriorX = 0, planePriorY = 0, planePriorZ = 0;
      planePostX = 0, planePostY = -0.5829, planePostZ = 0;
      planeRotX = 0, planeRotY = 0, planeRotZ = 267.401611;

      eaglePriorX = -1, eaglePriorY = 0.03, eaglePriorZ = 0.4;
      eaglePostX = 0, eaglePostY = 0.000001, eaglePostZ = 0;
      eagleRotX = 0, eagleRotY = 0, eagleRotZ = 43.981647;
    break;

    case 'u':
      //Pause the animation.
      paused = true;
      momentumBeforePause = momentum;
      momentum = 0;

      //Set frame.
      frame = -1;

      //Move the camera.
      cameraX = 0.000094;
      cameraY = -0.000036;
      cameraZ = -0.000103;
      cameraR = 42;

      //Reset animation object positions and rotations.
      planePriorX = 0, planePriorY = 0, planePriorZ = 0;
      planePostX = 0, planePostY = 0, planePostZ = 0;
      planeRotX = 0, planeRotY = 0, planeRotZ = 0;

      eaglePriorX = -0.5, eaglePriorY = 0.03, eaglePriorZ = -0.1;
      eaglePostX = 0, eaglePostY = 0, eaglePostZ = 0;
      eagleRotX = 0, eagleRotY = 0, eagleRotZ = 0;
    break;

    case 'h':
      printf("\n\n*** Controls ***\n\nW: Accelerate\nS: Decelerate\nA: Turn left\nD: Turn right\n=: Increase elevation\n-: Decrease elevation\n0: Stop moving\nSpace: Pause animation\n\nF: Fullscreen\nP: Set viewpoint A\nU: Set viewpoint B\nY: Set viewpoint C\n\nH: Help\nR: Reset\nQ: Quit");
    break;

    case 'f':
      if (fullscreen) {
        glutReshapeWindow(window_w, window_h);
        fullscreen = false;
      }
      else {
        window_w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        window_h = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        glutFullScreen();
        fullscreen = true;
      }

      forceReshape = true;
    break;
  }
}

void keyUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'w': momentumDirection--;  break;
    case 'a': rotationDirection++;  break;
    case 's': momentumDirection++;  break;
    case 'd': rotationDirection--;  break;
    case '=': elevationDirection++; break;
    case '-': elevationDirection--; break;
  }
}

//Entry point.
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  init(argc, argv);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, timer, 0);
  glutSetKeyRepeat(0);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyDown);
  glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't get any warnings or runtime exceptions." That's because OpenGL doesn't warn you or throws exceptions. Instead operations set global state which you can query to see if an action was successful. Which you should always do, even if it makes your code a bit less legible.

Comment: `The biggest change I've made is porting from SDL to GLUT, but I don't see how that would affect things.` You don't see how switching toolkits and the vast quantity of changes in your code that requires could possibly "affect things"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you cubic.

I added a debug snippet to help track down the problem:

```
if (DEBUG) {
  printf("%s\n", gluErrorString(glGetError()));
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

Using binary division, I quickly found that this line was erroring with 'invalid enumerant':

```
glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

This is because it should be:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

I have learnt a valuable lesson today.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if this solves your question! That way people know this is the answer they're looking for if they run into the same problem.

Comment: +1: And, just like that, the world gains another productive and useful software developer. :)